# Reqular expression is not working for inverse maching

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have tried the following 
If the input text contains "test" keyword then the output will be "NOT Match".

```
    String line = "placed test here";
    String pattern = "^((?!test).)*";
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find( )) {
        System.out.println("MATCH");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
```

Comment: `^(?!.*test)` would be enough ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing anchor `$`, use this regex:

```
^((?!test).)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xN4rZ8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*test).*
```

Comment: since we doing condition checking, you don't need to add the trailing `.*`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for pointing out. I didn't know whether the OP wants to extract the string too.